Execute the docker command in a Go test ran by Bazel
I have a Go test case that has a dependency on a library that internally makes a call to the below function:
func (c *DockerContainer) IsRunning() (bool, error) {
    cmd := exec.Command("docker", "ps", "--filter", "name=^"+c.Name+"$", "--format", "{{.ID}}")
    o, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        return false, exitError(cmd, err)
    }
    return len(o) > 0, nil
}

I'm able to execute the test with the go test command, but when run with bazel test it fails with the below error:
test panicked: failed to run command '/usr/local/bin/docker ps --filter name=^container-name$ --format {{.ID}}'

I tried to run the tests without the Bazel sandbox by adding the local tag, and using --spawn_strategy=standalone --strategy=GoTest=standalone but doesn't seem to work.
How do I make the tests execute outside Bazel's sandbox?

Bazel will be setting $PATH to /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:..
Is docker available on that $PATH? If the command works under bazel run but not bazel test, there's a good chance it is a $PATH or env var issue.
Do you have any other details about how or why it's failing?

I can run the command /usr/local/bin/docker ps --filter name=^container-name$ --format {{.ID}} directly and get an output. Also, go test  command works correctly. It fails only when ran using bazel test.

Does it run under bazel run?

whoa, it works if I do bazel run!
docker is available at /usr/local/bin/docker for me.

why would it not work for bazel test then?

Double check your env isn't getting overridden as part of the test setup
